# Manually Set Craft Commerce Currency

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to manually set the currency during the checkout process? Right now Im trying the following (set currency to CAD for Canadian buyers), which seems to break the cart array....

```
{% if cart.shippingAddress.countryId == '38' %}
  {% set cart = cart|merge({'paymentCurrency': 'CAD'}) %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/orders-carts.html), carts are represented by the [craft\commerce\elements\Order](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-elements-order.html) class. The [API documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/) is a useful way of finding available methods and properties. In this case, [Order::setPaymentCurrency](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-elements-order.html#method-setpaymentcurrency) seems to be what you're looking for. So this should work:

```
{% if cart.shippingAddress.countryId == '38' %}
  {% do cart.setPaymentCurrency('CAD') %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be working now just fine (after removing COMMERCE_PAYMENT_CURRENCY in my index file) and setting the paymentCurrency POST variable in my /pay form.

BUT -- any way to have the backend reflect the currencies actually charged? It seems to always show the store default on the order screen...

Comment: @DocumentServices Not sure about that, sorry. Maybe post that as a new question!